# Boot Camp and Windows 8

Tags: imac, macbook-pro, thunderbolt, target-display

I had a Retina MacBook Pro with Windows 8 already installed. I can boot from it without problems, and all the drivers Apple provided for Windows 7 works perfectly for me except one thing.

I am not able to use Target Display Mode with a Thunderbolt iMac. I understand that Boot Camp doesn't currently support Windows 8, but I am hoping someone has encountered this problem and solved it.

Also, I am able to connect to an HDMI or Mini Display Port-equipped display under Windows, and Target Display Mode works under OS X.

Answer (score -1):

Target Display mode is not supported under Boot Camp for any version of Windows, the best way to get that working is under a VM client suh as Parallels or VMWare

Comment: Apple docs said it's supported.